# How to implement an image and text switch on button click event?

Tags: android, onclick, textview, switch-statement

I'm trying to implement a button click event to switch images in an image switcher along with updating textView strings on button click.So far I've got it working for the image,but when I tried to modify the method to include updating the strings I'm getting the following errors:

1. On the getMyString call I get the following:The method getMyString(int, Context) in the type AboutActivity is not applicable for the 
    arguments (int)
2. At the method header of getMyString this: Multiple markers at this line

   - Syntax error on token "(", ; expected
   - Syntax error on token ")", ; expected
3. And where I'm calling the strings in the switch this: Void methods cannot return a value

   - Illegal modifier for parameter getMyString; only final is 
     permitted

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong with this implementation?I thought it may have been missing braces or that the code was placed out of context,but from looking at the errors it seems to be the way in which I'm calling the getMyString() in the onClick event.

```
public class AboutActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{


    private ImageSwitcher imageSwitcher;
    Button btnNext;
    TextView tView;


    int imageIds[]=
    {R.drawable.mark1,R.drawable.mark2,R.drawable.mark3};
    int messageCount=imageIds.length;
    // to keep current Index of ImageID array
    int currentIndex=-1;

    private int clicks = 1;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.about);

        final Intent intent1=new Intent(this,AboutActivity.class);
        final Intent intent2=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);

        final ViewGroup actionBarLayout = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.a,null);

        // get The references
        btnNext=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonNext);
        imageSwitcher = (ImageSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.imageSwitcher1);
        tView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        // Set the ViewFactory of the ImageSwitcher that will create ImageView object when asked
        imageSwitcher.setFactory(new ViewFactory() {
        public View makeView() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Create a new ImageView set it's properties
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new
        ImageSwitcher.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        return imageView;
        }
        });

     // Declare the animations and initialize them
        Animation in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
        Animation out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
        // set the animation type to imageSwitcher
        imageSwitcher.setInAnimation(in);
        imageSwitcher.setOutAnimation(out);
        // ClickListener for NEXT button
        // When clicked on Button ImageSwitcher will switch between Images
        // The current Image will go OUT and next Image will come in with specified animation
        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        currentIndex++;
        // If index reaches maximum reset it
        if(currentIndex==messageCount)
        currentIndex=0;
        imageSwitcher.setImageResource(imageIds[currentIndex]);
        tView.setText(getMyString(clicks++, v.getContext()));
        }

        });


        // Set up your ActionBar
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setCustomView(actionBarLayout);

        // You customization
        final int actionBarColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.action_bar);
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(actionBarColor));

        final Button actionBarHome = (Button) findViewById(R.id.action_bar_title);
        actionBarHome.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_action_back);
        actionBarHome.setOnClickListener(this);
        actionBarHome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {                

               startActivity(intent2);

            }

        });

        final Button actionBarInfo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.action_bar_staff);
        actionBarInfo.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_action_help);
        actionBarInfo.setOnClickListener(this);
        actionBarInfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {                

               startActivity(intent1);

            }

        });


    }

    //method called to update textview strings.
    public String getMyString(int variable, Context applicationContext){
        switch(variable){
            case 1:
                return applicationContext.getResources().getString(R.string.cutString);
                break;
            case 2:
                return applicationContext.getResources().getString(R.string.markString);
                break;
            case 3:
                return applicationContext.getResources().getString(R.string.measureString);
                break;
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1.On the getMyString call I get the following:The method getMyString(int, Context) in the type AboutActivity is not applicable for the arguments (int)

You have

```
 tView.setText(getMyString(clicks++));
```

only passing it an `int` as the error says but them method takes `(int, Context)`. So it should be

```
 tView.setText(getMyString(clicks++, v.getContext()));
```

So that you are passing it the correct `params` that the method takes.

> 2At the method header of getMyString this: Multiple markers at this line - Syntax error on token "(", ; expected - Syntax error on token ")", ; expected

It looks like your `getMyString()` method is inside `onCreate()` or some other method. Move it outside of any method.

> 3.And where I'm calling the strings in the switch this: Void methods cannot return a value - Illegal modifier for parameter getMyString; only final is permitted

I think this is also due to your method being inside of another method but the way its set up its a little confusing what's going on. Make these changes and run again and see what errors you get.

**Edit**

You need to have the method `return` a `String` and right now it won't return one if none of the `cases` are true`. Therefore, you can have a final`return`where you return a default`String` value in case non of them match. Or you can do something like this

```
/method called to update textview strings.
public String getMyString(int variable, Context applicationContext){
    String text = "";  // create a String variable to return and give it whatever 
                       // value you want in case none of the cases return true
    switch(variable){  // assign the variable below
        case 1:
            text = applicationContext.getResources().getString(R.string.cutString);
            break;
        case 2:
            text = applicationContext.getResources().getString(R.string.markString);
            break;
        case 3:
            text = applicationContext.getResources().getString(R.string.measureString);
            break;
    }
  return text; //just one return

}
```

Comment: Okay,so that fixed the first error.I placed the method outside of the onCreate() but it's still giving errors,second errors is now: This method must return a result of type String and last error : "unreachable code". If I post the complete class in the above question,could you take a quick look? Thanks

Comment: I posted the complete class to get a better idea of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: The above is edited with your suggestions and getMyString moved outside of the onCreate()

Comment: See my edit. I added the code that should work with comments in code.

Comment: Now just to add swiping to the app.I'm trying to find a good tutorial on it but its hard to see where the bits of code fit into my app.Do you know decent one off hand?

Comment: No, but you can try vogella.com. He normally seems to have decent tutorials on a variety of APIs

Comment: I just ran through this functionality,but there's a flaw in the implementation.After I step through the three images the corresponding strings show but after the first three clicks the strings disappear. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I'm not sure if I completely understand but maybe because you don't reset `clicks` after it reaches 3 so there is no `String` to be returned in `getMyString()` so it returns ""

Comment: so how would I reset it to beginning of the loop? I'll have a think about this one.

Comment: If I understand what you want, then you can just put `clicks = 0;` in `case 3`

Comment: Okay,I'll give that a try.To clarify I'm trying to reset the string to the first string after the 3rd click.At the moment after the 3rd click the strings in the textview disappear.

Comment: In that case you can change `String text = ""` to initialize to whatever your first `String` is

Comment: I just tried to run the application on the emulator after addidng a new imageView to the main activity,haptic feedback on the calculate button and a scrollview to the main activity but it crashed before it opened.I can't make any sense of the errors I'm getting.Could you take a look at them if you get a chance? link to pastebin: http://pastebin.com/PAYrjHCL

Comment: Clean your project, "Project --> Clean..." if that doesn't work you will need to make a new post with the logcat and relevant code

Comment: link to question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966201/app-crashing-after-adding-a-scrollview-and-imageview

Answer (score 0):

I think one error is the following: in the onClick() function, you call the getMyString function with the integer clicks as the only input parameter, while in the definition of the getMyString function, you say that the function has to receive an integer AND the applicationContext. I would suggest to make the call of the getMyString function like this:

```
 tView.setText(getMyString(clicks++, getApplicationContext()));
```

Answer (score 0):

> On the getMyString call I get the following:The method
>   getMyString(int, Context) in the type AboutActivity is not applicable
>   for the arguments (int)

Becasuse you don't have a method which only gets an integer as a parameter. Your method get 2 paramters:

```
String getMyString(int variable, Context applicationContext)
```

Anyway solution; change this:

```
tView.setText(getMyString(clicks++));
```

To this:

```
tView.setText(getMyString(clicks++), v.getContext());
```